# Capturing desktop video and microphone audio from a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webrtc, getusermedia

I am using the navigator.webkitGetUserMedia API to capture the desktop and using microphone to capture audio. When I make the following call

```
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({
     audio:true,  
     video: {
     mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
        chromeMediaSourceId: id,
        maxWidth:screen.width,
        maxHeight:screen.height} 
     }
  }, gotStream, getUserMediaError);
```

I am getting a screen capture error. Does this API not support the above scenario?

I am able to capture audio and desktop video individually but not together. Also, since I am capturing desktop and not the webcam video, does that make any difference?

Answer (score 3):

Chrome does not allow you to request an audio stream alongside a `chromeMediaSource`.

See **Why Screen Sharing Fails** [here](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/screen-sharing/) for more info.

You may be able to circumvent this by sending individual `getUserMedia` requests - one for the audio stream and one for desktop.

Comment: thank you for your response. I tried that as well. Having two separate streams. but for some reason the audio is not at all clear. It becomes gibberish noise. Any clue around that?

Comment: Can you please share the code how to handle 2 different streams case?